# I can't start the php server in EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I'm pretty new on AWS, I've tried to start my php chat, but when I use the command *php chat-server.php*, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on "tcp://0.0.0.0:8080": Address already in use in /var/www/html/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php(36): React\Socket\TcpServer->__construct('tcp://0.0.0.0:8...', Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop), Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(59): React\Socket\Server->__construct('0.0.0.0:8080', Object(React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop))
#2 /var/www/html/chat-server.php(15): Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(Object(Ratchet\Http\HttpServer), 8080)
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php on line 164
```

I'm using Ratchet, it really Works on my computer, I can text with the other browser, but in the EC2 I have this error, and it's impossible to start the server, please help me with that

Comment: Please, can someone help me?

Comment: The error is evident - you're already using 0.0.0.0:8080 somewhere.

Comment: So, which port do you recommend to use?

Comment: I saw that php is running with this port 8080, how can I fix it? 
php        6718 ec2-user    3u  IPv4  81696      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)

Comment: Have a look at your httpd.conf file for your server. Make the changes there, then restart your server.

Comment: Oh, I did it, but I see the port 80 there, not 8080. So what can I do? Change the port to listen to 8080 or let it as 80, and what more? Please help me, I'm really blind

Comment: Without more insight to your setup I'd only be guessing at the changes to be made.

Comment: Never mind, I don't want to take your time, you already helped me a lot, you're a good man, I will keep trying, someday this will work. Thanks a lot, thx, thx, thx!

Comment: you're welcome. I wish there was more that I could do, but that would likely be way out of scope here on Stack Overflow. Have you considered opening a support ticket with AWS?

Comment: No, I didn't think about it, but I will do what you said, thank you very much again, you helped me a lot, I wish you all the best, that you receive everything you did twice